# Sum of all matching elements inside a time frame that changes according to the element in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I searched a lot before asking this question here but couldn't find anything related to my problem.

I am currently trying to get a specific value (let's call it "sum in reference period") to be retrieved from my Oracle SQL database.

I have different elements that are linked to a group (e.g. element A is from Group 1, element B is from Group 2, element C is from Group 3, etc.) and each element has the date when it was created in the following format: YYYYMM.

How do I create an additional column with the sum of all elements that are from the same group as the element in the row and that were created in the last 12 months from the element creation?

Let's say my current table looks like this:

```
| Element_Id | Creation_Date | Group |
| A          | 202101        | 1     |
| B          | 202101        | 2     |
| C          | 202101        | 3     |
| D          | 202102        | 1     |
| E          | 202001        | 1     |
| F          | 202002        | 1     |
| G          | 202003        | 1     |
```

and what I want the result to be is:

```
| Element_Id | Creation_Date | Group | Sum_In_Reference_Period |
| A          | 202101        | 1     | 3                       |
| B          | 202101        | 2     | 1                       | 
| C          | 202101        | 3     | 1                       |
| D          | 202102        | 1     | 3                       |
| E          | 202001        | 1     | 1                       |
| F          | 202002        | 1     | 2                       |
| G          | 202003        | 1     | 3                       |
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: sorry...I will add an example in the question

Comment: Why has `D` got a sum of `2` when `D`, `A` and `G` are all in the same group and are less than 12 months before `D`'s creation date?

Comment: sorry, it was a mistake of mine, I changed it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a windowed analytic function:

```sql
SELECT t.*,
       COUNT(*) OVER (
         PARTITION BY grp
         ORDER BY TO_DATE(Creation_Date || '01', 'YYYYMMDD')
         RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL '11' MONTH PRECEDING AND INTERVAL '0' MONTH FOLLOWING
       ) AS sum_in_reference_period
FROM   table_name t
ORDER BY element_id
```

Which, for your sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (Element_Id, Creation_Date, Grp) AS
SELECT 'A', 202101, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', 202101, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'C', 202101, 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'D', 202102, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'E', 202001, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'F', 202002, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'G', 202003, 1 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | ELEMENT_ID | CREATION_DATE | GRP | SUM_IN_REFERENCE_PERIOD |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | A | 202101 | 1 | 3 |
> | B | 202101 | 2 | 1 |
> | C | 202101 | 3 | 1 |
> | D | 202102 | 1 | 3 |
> | E | 202001 | 1 | 1 |
> | F | 202002 | 1 | 2 |
> | G | 202003 | 1 | 3 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=71ee9f1fc85c3766b58fb71496f5f2ac)*